# Wordpress ; get_userdata is not working on this page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting nuts with this... a simple function is not working anymore, and I don't understand why. This code is part a personal plugin. Theses lines are part of a function that has troubles ; the php turns into errors and I located the error in this last line shown here below.

```
$marecherche = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta 
                                WHERE meta_key='birth_date' AND meta_value='{$americanDate}'");
        //si on a trouvé + d'1 personne, il faut affiner la recherche
        if ($wpdb->num_rows == 1) {
        
            $my_user = $marecherche[0]->user_id ;
            echo "<br>found:{$my_user}";
            $found_user = get_userdata( $my_user );
```

What I do not understand is that the $marecherche  returns expected result. But when I call "get_userdata" the page turns into error.
I even tried

```
$found_user = get_userdata( 2 );
```

and I obtain the same result (of course I have an user with ID 2)

Comment: "the page turns into error".  what error exactly?

Comment: try `get_user_by( 'id', 2 )` (assuming your really have a used with id 2)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* instead of using Query , we have wordpress function available to use */
/* i have tried to write a code from you question so you can try below code for above issue , this may give you solution */  
      $my_users = new WP_User_Query( 
                      array(                
                         'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'birth_date',
                            'value'   => $americanDate,
                            'compare' => '='
                        ))
                      ));
      $data = $my_users->get_results();
```